# Ajax.BeginForm add ModelSstate error sent from controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a ajax form in my view

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AttendeeAvailability", "Response", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "done" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    ....
    //some stuff
    ....
}
<script type="text/javascript">

    function done() {
     //do something;
    }
</script>
```

Here is the post method of controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AttendeeAvailability(AttendeeAvailableDateTime response)
{            
    ....
    ....
    if (somecheck1)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,"Check error1");
        return View();
    }
    if (doesTimeExists2)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,"Check error2");
        return View();
    }
    //do some database actions
    return View();
}
```

Currently I'm not getting any Modelstate's error message that is being set in controller.

I'm guessing because it calls the done function that I have in view when tasks in controller are completed successfully.

How can I send some errors and display them as Modelstate error in this case?

Comment: An AJAX request (which means the submit also) returns data that the browser might use to update part of the document (it can refresh the whole document, but that's an entire different story). Your page does not get fully refreshed. Which means that you don't have access to the `ModelState`. I mean, you do, but it's the original one, for the "clean" page. If you change the `Ajax.BeginForm` to a "regular" form, your web page will be fully refreshed and you'll get the `ModelState`.

Comment: so how can I send some error message and display them? Any approach?

Comment: You can send back a Json object/string and process is in the `done()` function.

Comment: Could you guide me through how my done function would look like as an answer. I don't have much experience with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the form call header (add a parameter to the `done` function):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AttendeeAvailability", "Response", 
     new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "done(data)" }))
```

...and the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function done(data) {
    //do something with the data
    }
</script>
```

How your `data` looks depends entirely on how you structure it in your action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult AttendeeAvailability(AttendeeAvailableDateTime response)
{            
   ....
   ....
   if (somecheck1)
   {
        //ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,"Check error1");
        return Json(new { error = "Check error1" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   if (doesTimeExists2)
   {
       //ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,"Check error2");
       return Json(new { error = "Check error2" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }

   //do some database actions
   return Json(new { success = "Success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Following this, you can access the data by parsing it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function done(data) {
        var confirmation = data;
        if (confirmation["success"] != undefined) {
           alert(confirmation["success"]);
        }
        else if (confirmation["error"] != undefined) {
           alert(confirmation["error"]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: haha I actually meant how would I show the message as ModelStateError are normally shown. Which is `//do something with the data` but nvm. May be I didn't explain myself properly

Comment: Basically, every AJAX request will receive some data from the server. You can use this data to either update an element (`UpdateTargetId`) or to pass whatever custom data/messages you want or need.

Comment: So I can have a div inside the form and update that div content from javascript function with the message passed from controller right?

Comment: Exactly. Once you get the data back from the server you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: in your `return Json(new { error = "Check error2", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` are you missing`}` i've been trying to put in different places but may be because i'm putting in wrong place i'm getting console error in browser

Comment: @Biplov13, yeah, sorry about that. I was kind of in a hurry to finish the answer before having to go. Anyway, the lack of `}` would cause a compilation error and not a JavaScript console message (edited). The error in the console (probably `unexpected token`) originated from me trying to parse a JavaScript object and not a JSON string. The returned object is automatically parsed so you don't need to call `JSON.parse(data)` (also edited). It should work now.

Comment: On a related note, in such scenarios, it would be helpful to inspect the JavaScript code. Add a `debugger;` as the first line in the `done` function and open the developer tools of your browser. When the execution reaches that point, it should stop and allow you to debug/inspect your variables. It would then be obvious that the returned data is already a JavaScript object.

Comment: Thanks! I was adding alerts and checking values. Will give a shot once again :)

Comment: I've added it as question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655280/mvc-while-retrieving-the-passed-json-object-from-controller-in-view-javascript