# MVC: While retrieving the passed Json object from controller in view, JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm passing some string messages as Json object in view.

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(someObject object)
{            
    .....
    .....
    
    if (check1)
    {
        return Json(new { error = Resource.someMessage1},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    if(check2)
    {
        return Json(new { error = Resource.someMessage2}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
 
    //some stuffs

    return Json(new {success = "success"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I want to retrieve the messages passed from controller and alert from My view

in view I have some javascript

```
function done(data) {
    alert("hello");
    var message = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(message);
    if (message["error"] != undefined) {
        alert(message["error"]);
    } else {
     //do some stuff

    }
};
```

what I was expecting is if passed message from controller is type error then I would get alert with the message.

The line `alert("hello");` but there is no alert after that.
I get error in console

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: console the value present in the "data" and share it here, want to know what is passed to this `done()` function.

Comment: @Biplov..can you post your view code?

Comment: You mean the response sent? If yes, then this is what I see as response in browser `{"error":"somemessage"}`. If no, I probably didn't understand what u meant, sorry. Quite new to this front end thing

Comment: @Biplov..there is no need to parse the data

Comment: @AvinashKothamasu but when I alert data I get `[object object]` as alert

Comment: @Biplov..see my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variable type is detected as json object.

```
var x = {"error":"somemessage"};
alert(x.error)
```

The variable is detected as String here.

`var x = JSON.parse('{"error":"somemessage"}');
alert(x.error)`

If you notice, the difference is #1 starts with {(curly braces) whereas #2 starts with '(apostrophe)

Answer (score 2):

If you execute the following line of code

```
var a = { success : "success" };
var b = JSON.parse(a);
```

you will get the error you have mentioned about "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o..."

Don't know why are you trying to convert your already JSON object using JSON.parse(), instead you could use this

```
a.success
```

to read the "success" value .

Answer (score 0):

Try not parsing the answer (so remove "JSON.parse(data)" line) and read everything directly from "data" variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `data.sucess` to get your result . There is no need to parse again.